# How to fix warning occured during compiling of C program on fedora

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

I am trying to learn how to split a c program in more than one file but during compilation it throws warning as given below:

```sh
$ gcc ./p1.c ./p2.c -o ./p1
./p2.c:2:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
    2 | b = 6;
      | ^
./p2.c:2:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘b’ [-Wimplicit-int]
```

where,
`p1.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "p2.h"
int a = 5;

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("%d\n", b);
    printf("%d\n", square(b));
    return 0;
}
```

`p2.c`

```c
#include "./p2.h"
b = 6;
int square(int x) {
    return x * x;
}
```

and `p2.h`

```c
#ifndef P2_H
#define P2_H

extern int b;
int square(int);

#endif
```

all of these files are present in same directory but i am still getting the warning, after trying several searching on the internet i can't find how to fix it.

Thank You In Advance.

Comment: You need to specify the type of `b` when you're providing its definition, not just when providing an `extern` declaration. Change `b = 6;` to `int b = 6;`. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)

Comment: Please don't use the C++ tag for C questions.  Removed.

Comment: As a side note, since you're wondering about warnings: do yourself a favor and use `-Wall -Wextra` with *gcc*. That catches a lot of mistakes you should just fix (even when harmless).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p2.c` should have a normal definition of the global variable:

```
#include "./p2.h"
int b = 6;
int square(int x) {
    return x * x;
}
```